# alpine.js x-for update is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I've created a simple `x-for` loop on some data from Alpine Store (need it to be global)
My goal is to update a specific row **after** the table was drawn by the `x-for`

Codepen: https://codepen.io/roniwashere/pen/oNMgGyy

```html
<div x-data>
  <table border="1">
    <template x-for="(row,index) in $store.test.rows" :key="row.key">
      <tr><td x-text="row.title"></td></tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
<button @click="$store.test.change(1,'testD','d')">replace</button>
```

```js
Alpine.store('test',{
 rows: [
  {'title':'testA','key':'a'},
  {'title':'testB','key':'b'},
  {'title':'testC','key':'c'}
 ],
  change(index,title,key){
     this.rows[index] = {'title':title,'key':key};
  }
});

Alpine.start();
```

And i'm getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')` (even though the table has the data displayed)

[image: screenshot from codepen]

I couldn't find anywhere in the docs about this, if I reset `rows` using `Alpine.store('test').rows = [];` works, it clears the table.

But updating the row doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is outside of `x-data` block, hence it tries to access something outside its scope.

So if you put it inside, code will work:

```html
<div x-data>
  <table border="1">
    <template x-for="(row,index) in $store.test.rows" :key="row.key">
      <tr><td x-text="row.title"></td></tr>
    </template>
  </table>

  <button @click="$store.test.change(1,'testD','d')">replace</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, actually the button should be outside, I've updated the code - I meant to use `Alpine.store('test')` syntax which is not working for me

Comment: reverted my question change - your answer is correct and it's best to just move the button to be inside the scope of the x-data block